# pandas: find log of each column divided by scalar from another dataframe based on column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of data as follows:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(index=pandas.date_range('20200101', '20200107'), 
                      columns=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 
                      data=numpy.random.rand(7,3))
```

> ```
> print(df)
>
>                  foo       bar       baz
> 2020-01-01  0.641336  0.185073  0.815814
> 2020-01-02  0.616637  0.438274  0.750864
> 2020-01-03  0.336463  0.548659  0.661161
> 2020-01-04  0.924278  0.560541  0.341154
> 2020-01-05  0.608545  0.674169  0.242851
> 2020-01-06  0.459625  0.816147  0.113926
> 2020-01-07  0.781475  0.865262  0.625729
> ```

I have another dataframe of factors for each column:

```
fac = pandas.DataFrame(index=['foo','bar','baz'],
                       data={'factor':[1,2,3]})
```

> ```
> print(fac)
>
>      factor
> foo       1
> bar       2
> baz       3
> ```

I would like to calculate the log of each row, divided by the respective column's factor

akin to:

```
numpy.log(df['foo']) / fac['foo'] # for each column, foo, bar, baz
```

I have found the following solution, which creates a copy of `df`, and then iterates over each column, setting the value in the copied dataframe to the result of the expression I want to calculate.

```
res = df.copy()
for c in df.columns:
    res[c] = numpy.log(df[c]) / fac.loc[c].values
```

> ```
> print(res)
>
>                  foo       bar       baz
> 2020-01-01 -0.444202 -0.843503 -0.067856
> 2020-01-02 -0.483475 -0.412456 -0.095510
> 2020-01-03 -1.089267 -0.300139 -0.137919
> 2020-01-04 -0.078743 -0.289427 -0.358474
> 2020-01-05 -0.496685 -0.197138 -0.471769
> 2020-01-06 -0.777345 -0.101580 -0.724067
> 2020-01-07 -0.246572 -0.072361 -0.156279
> ```

It works, but it doesn't feel very ergonomic.

Is there a better, recommended way to achieve the same (ideally in a one-liner)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide a dataframe by a series. In doing so, Pandas will align the dataframe's columns to the series' index. So this can be done with just:

```
np.log(df)/fac['factor']
```

Output:

```
                 foo       bar       baz
2020-01-01 -0.444202 -0.843502 -0.067856
2020-01-02 -0.483475 -0.412455 -0.095510
2020-01-03 -1.089267 -0.300139 -0.137919
2020-01-04 -0.078742 -0.289426 -0.358474
2020-01-05 -0.496684 -0.197137 -0.471769
2020-01-06 -0.777344 -0.101580 -0.724069
2020-01-07 -0.246572 -0.072361 -0.156279
```

Comment: As simple as that! Thank you!

Comment: Congrats on 100k !

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks :-)